# Flushing Fabric/Crashlytics non fatals and events

Tags: android, google-fabric

I have an Android app that's deployed on a bunch of tablets my company owns and manages. These tablets are single purpose devices - they run this app and nothing else. The app doesn't ever stop unless it crashes. In fact, we use AirWatch to lock the device into single task mode, so it's more or less impossible for the app to get killed.

From what I've read, this does not sit well with Fabric, which likes to send its non fatal errors and events only once the app is killed.

What can I do about this? Can I turn this behaviour off or somehow programmatically flush the list of events and non fatals to be sent to the server?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a workaround? I am in a similar situation.

Comment: You can use Firebase Analytics events I guess, but they're not really the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. There isn't a way to manually flush or push the events to our servers currently. It's not on our immediate roadmap to add in, but will update my answer if there is a change.

Comment: Thanks, Mike from Fabric.

Comment: Helps with the 15 character requirement :)

Comment: I am in a similar but less extreme situation. Is there a workaround? My app may die eventually or it may be backgrounded at some point so I am more concerned about how long the data lives in Fabric's cache so I don't lose it.

Comment: As long as you're not logging a very high volume of data, then the cache should suffice.